# What is the correct way to return models to the list of entities owned by the related one?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

I am doing a small project on Fastapi (my first project on it), python 3.10, using sqlalchemy, sqlmodel.
I have 2 test models: shop and product.
I want the endpoint `shop` to return the following structure:

```
{
  "name": "Adidas",
  "id": 1,
  "is_main": true,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "sneakers",
      "shop_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "T-shirt",
      "shop_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

[Full test project on Github](https://github.com/GennadyShelukhin/python_fastapi_sqlmodel_example/blob/main/app/models/shop.py)

I use [Relationship() from SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/relationships/):

`models`

`product.py`

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Optional

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from app.models.shop import Shop


class ProductBase(SQLModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    shop_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="shop.id")


class Product(ProductBase, table=True):

    __tablename__ = "product"

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    shop: Optional["Shop"] = Relationship(back_populates="products")


class ProductRead(ProductBase):
    id: int


class ProductCreate(ProductBase):
    pass
```

`shop.py`

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, List, Optional

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from app.models.product import Product, ProductRead


class ShopBase(SQLModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None


class Shop(ShopBase, table=True):

    __tablename__ = "shop"

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    products: List["Product"] = Relationship(back_populates="shop")


class ShopRead(ShopBase):
    id: int


class ShopGet(ShopRead):
    products: List["ProductRead"] = []
    is_main: bool = True


class ShopCreate(ShopBase):
    pass
```

`repositories`

`product.py`

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlalchemy.future import select
from app.models.product import Product, ProductCreate
from app.repositories.base import BaseRepository


class ProductRepository(BaseRepository):

    async def create(self, product: ProductCreate) -> Product:
        db_product = Product.from_orm(product)
        self.session.add(db_product)
        await self.session.commit()
        await self.session.refresh(db_product)
        return db_product

    async def get_by_id(self, product_id: int) -> Optional[Product]:
        result = await self.session.get(Product, int(product_id))
        return result
```

`shop.py`

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlalchemy.future import select
from app.models.shop import Shop, ShopCreate, ShopGet
from app.repositories.base import BaseRepository


class ShopRepository(BaseRepository):

    async def create(self, shop: ShopCreate) -> Shop:
        db_shop = Shop.from_orm(shop)
        self.session.add(db_shop)
        await self.session.commit()
        await self.session.refresh(db_shop)
        return db_shop

    async def get_by_id(self, shop_id: int) -> Optional[ShopGet]:
        result = await self.session.get(Shop, int(shop_id))
        return result
```

`endpoints`

`shop.py`

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Query
from app.repositories.shop import ShopRepository
from app.models.shop import Shop, ShopCreate, ShopGet
from app.endpoints.depends import get_shop_repository


router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/get_by_id", response_model=ShopGet)
async def get_by_id(
        shop_id: int = Query(description="Shop ID"),
        shop: ShopRepository = Depends(get_shop_repository)):
    return await shop.get_by_id(shop_id=shop_id)


@router.post("/create", response_model=Shop)
async def create(
        name: str = Query(description="Shop name"),
        shop: ShopRepository = Depends(get_shop_repository)):
    return await shop.create(shop=ShopCreate(name=name))
```

`db connect`

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession

from app import settings


async_engine = create_async_engine(settings.db_async_connection_str, echo=True, future=True)


async def get_async_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(
        bind=async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
    )
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

I have 2 problems:

1. Exception `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class` when open swagger.
   Reason:

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from app.models.product import Product, ProductRead

class ShopGet(ShopRead):
    products: List["ProductRead"] = []
```

But this is necessary due to [circular imports](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/code-structure/?h=import#make-circular-imports-work)

2. Main problem:

Endpoint `shop` (shop_id=1) return empty products list. [Details](https://github.com/GennadyShelukhin/python_fastapi_sqlmodel_example/blob/main/app/models/shop.py). There are 2 products in the database with shop_id=1.

[This question in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415495/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC)

Comment: Since you haven't included the _actual_ endpoint you're querying, it's hard to say why you're not getting any returned information. Have you checked whether the `products` property has any content in your view method before returning it to the user?

Comment: Added code examples with endpoint to the question. Endpoint `shop`, `get_by_id`, `shop_id=1`. There are 2 products in the database with `shop_id=1`. Expected response: json at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that sqlalchemy loads relations lazily. In synchronous environment it can load relations when you try to access them, but in asynchronous environment it is impossible. So you need to ask sqlalchemy to explicitly preload relations.

```py
class ShopRepository(BaseRepository):

    ...

    async def get_by_id(self, shop_id: int) -> Optional[ShopGet]:
        query = select(Shop).where(Shop.id == shop_id).options(selectinload(Shop.products))
        return (await session.execute(query)).scalars().one()
```

Comment: This seems to be true, but this option did not work.

1) 
`query = select(Shop).options(selectinload(Shop)).where(Shop.id == shop_id)`, error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: mapper option expects string key or list of attributes`

Comment: `query = select(Shop).options(selectinload(Shop.products)).where(Shop.id == shop_id)`, error: `AttributeError: type object 'Shop' has no attribute 'products'`

Comment: 3) `query = select().options(selectinload(Shop)).where(Shop.id == shop_id)`, response: null

Comment: Maybe here you can find soultion: https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/74

Comment: Thank you! The solution did not help in my case, but I found there a link to [a repository with an example of how to organize a project](https://github.com/jonra1993/fastapi-alembic-sqlmodel-async). I think I will completely reconsider my approach.